# Call By Need in Scheme

Tags: parameters, scheme, parameter-passing, anonymous-recursion, call-by-need

I have this code knowing that parameters are passed using *call by need:*

```
(define fact-2
  (let ((foo (lambda (n f)
               (if (zero? n)
                   1
                   (f n f)))))
    (lambda (n)
      (let ((res 1))
        (foo n (begin 
                 (set! res (* res n)) 
                 (set! n (- n 1)) 
                 foo)) 
        res))))
```

I feel like I am missing something, but in the *call by need* calling `foo` with this object as `f`, it will calculate `f` once and then will never update `res` and `n`. Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: After the first call to `foo`, `foo` calls itself in an infinite loop. Since `foo` is just calling itself, the numeric argument `n` is never decremented, so never reaches zero to terminate the loop.

Comment: Well, based on my teacher you are wrong, it somehow supposed to keep updating n in the (begin ... ) but I do not understand why since in call by need it should do it once

Comment: You can show it easily by adding a little output. Add a line like `(display "Enter foo: n: ")(display n)(newline)` as the first line in `foo`. Then invoke `(fact-2 5)`. You will see an unending stream of output where `foo` is called with an argument of 4.

Comment: @clartaq -- _call by need_ is a lazy evaluation model, and Scheme eagerly evaluates arguments in function calls. You can't just run this code in a Scheme REPL to reason about its behavior under a call by need model.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Only with *call-by-name* the `begin` expression will get evaluated on each call to `f` (except for the very first time) -- to find out what it is that we're calling, *only if* the call to `f` is indeed made.

With *call-by-value* the `begin` expression will be evaluated only once, before the very first call to `foo`.

With *call-by-need* it *might* get evaluated at most once, when and if at the end of the very first call to `foo` there's a need to call `f` again.

---

Let's look at how a *call-by-name* version could be simulated in the regular *call-by-value* Scheme:

```
(define fact2
  (let ((foo (lambda (n f)
               (if (zero? (n))       ;; (n)   NB
                   1
                   ((f) n f)))))     ;; (f)   NB
    (lambda (n)
      (let ((res 1))
        (foo (lambda () n)           ;; (lambda () ...)    NB
             (lambda ()              ;; (lambda () ...)    NB
               (begin 
                 (set! res (* res n)) 
                 (set! n (- n 1)) 
                 foo))) 
        res))))
```

Calling `(fact2 5)` produces `120` in Racket.

For *call-by-value* semantics your code needs no changes (to be interpreted in the regular *call-by-value* Scheme) and will of course loop, for the `(fact-2 5)` call (and indeed does so, in Racket).

And under the *call-by-need* semantics each lambda's body (of the two new lambda wrappers) will be evaluated only for the very first time it is called, whereupon it will save the calculated value and then return it; and for all the subsequent calls the saved value will be immediately returned, without evaluating the body. Thus the `set!` forms will be evaluated at most once, and the code, with the example test call  `(fact-2 5)` will, again, loop.

Comment: Could you explain some more? I only see `fact-2` calling `foo` with the arguments `n` and `foo`. And `foo` only calls `foo` with the arguments `n` and `foo`. Nowhere does `foo` decrement `n`. And I don't see any memoization or other mechanics for laziness being set up.

Comment: @clartaq explain specifically what? there's three statements in my answer.  are you asking about call by need? what exactly, specifically, is your question please?

Comment: Yes, about "call by need" (or any other parameter passing convention). I just don't see how any call to `fact-2` can succeed if there is no visible way to stop `foo` from recursing. Otherwise, I'll repeat the O.P.s question. "Am I missing something?" Thank you for persisting.

Comment: @clartaq I've edited the answer. :) under call-by-value the OP code needs no changes and will of course loop, for the `(fact-2 5)` call.

Comment: Thank you. And I thought continuations were mind-bending.

Comment: that's mutation for you. :) interestingly, I only had the lambda wrapping for the `foo` argument, at first. I thought, `n` is a plain numeric value, it needs no wrapping. can you guess what happened when I tried it? :)  (and thanks for the discussion!)

Comment: Wouldn't even venture a guess.

Comment: why it looped of course. can you see why? (I couldn't, at first) ...... 1.6K miles above Mars, yay!

Comment: It isn't obvious to me. Stepped away to watch Perseverance touchdown too.

Comment: it's about _____scope_____. one `n` was being mutated, another one was being tested in the `if`. but with the lambda it's the same `n`, so it works.

Comment: load it up in Racket, hit Debug. :) cheers.

Comment: "_Under the call-by-value semantics your code needs no changes and will of course loop, for the `(fact-2 5)` call._" -- Maybe I misunderstand your meaning, but under call-by-value semantics the `begin` form will be evaluated when `foo` is first called (evaluating to `foo`), so on subsequent `(foo n foo)` calls, there will be no calls to `set!`, no decrement of `n`, and non-terminating looping.

Comment: @adabsurdum "... and there will occur non-terminating looping." yes, that's it. what I meant was, we had to make some changes to represent the call-by-name interpretation of OP's code, to represent it by a code to be run inside Racket's call-by-value system; so there's no need for any changes to represent its call-by-value interpretation, as Racket is already that.